# Showing UIImage in UITableVIewCell - using too much ram?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to show images on the left side on UITableViewCell, and it is working. However my app is using 80-90mb RAM while running - and it is because of the images. When I remove the code that adds the images to the UITableViewCell, then the usage drops to only 5 mb RAM.

- `self.imagesInArray` = NSMutableArray with all my images
- The imageview is added in the Interface Builder and then I access it
  with [cell viewWithTag:10]
- The images are loaded in my array imagesInArray. The images comes
  from a server (Parse).

```c
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    UIImageView *picture = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    if (picture.image == nil) {
        UIImage *image = [self.imagesInArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

How can I optimize this so it runs more efficient? The 80-90mb RAM usage is happening with under 10 images - surely I am missing something. Open for any ideas.

Comment: I'd say optimize your images, a lot. According to what you're saying, each image is at least 8mb. It should be a couple kb only. Where do they come from?

Comment: @pacman321 the total size for my images are only 2mb. I don't think the problem is the image sizes. They are too small to cause that kind of a problem. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you download all the images from a server or are they retrieved locally? If you download them, you could use a lib like this one https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: @pacman321 I download them from Parse.com asynchronously, convert NSData to UIImage and then add them in a NSMutableArray. The memory usage problem occurs when the images gets loaded in the UIImageView as shown above.

Comment: @Mardev it seems that your code *doesn't do anything with UIImageView* (your get link to UIImage but doesn't set it to UIImageView). So your app can't leak here. Is this code the same you're using in app?

Comment: @Mardev ah, you post comment below that all is OK now with smallest images. Cool!

Comment: @AntonGaenko yes, I don't know where my comment went. But everything is cool now - I just resize the original picture and upload it to my server as a thumbnail and use that. The memory drops and everything is smoother. The resolution of the images were way to high before.